# Running infinite loop to receive and send data in GUI | MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, parallel-processing, matlab-guide, xbee

I'm working on a project for transmitting data via [XBees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) from one laptop to another. I have done with the GUI interface, but I have a problem with the receiving part. As the receiver doesn't know the exact time the file is going to be received, I wrote an infinite loop which is:

```
    recv=[];
    while (1)

        while s.BytesAvailable==0
        end

        a=fscanf(s);
        recv=[recv a]

    end
```

How can I run this `for` loop all the time, starting from the very beginning of the program till the user close the program, and the user still be able to chose different data to transmit it?

In other words; dividing the duty into two parts receiving parts always running; while transmitting part works only when the user wants to transmit data...

Comment: You could check out this fancy article: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab support asynchronous read operations, triggered when the port receives data. The trigger can be a minimum number of bytes, or a special character.

You have to use the [`BytesAvailableFcn`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/bytesavailablefcn.html) callback property.

You can use `setappdata` and `getappdata` to store arrays too large to fit within the input buffer of the port.
Assuming you save the handle of the main figure into a variable named `hfig`:

in the main gui code:

```
s.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 1 ;                           %// number of byte to receive before the callback is triggered
s.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte' ;
s.BytesAvailableFcn = {@myCustomReceiveFunction,hfig} ;  %// function to execute when the 'ByteAvailable' event is triggered.

recv = [] ;                                              %// initialize the variable
setappdata( hfig , 'LargeReceivedPacket' , recv )        %// store it into APPDATA
```

and as a separate function:

```
function myCustomReceiveFunction(hobj,evt,hfig)
    %// retrieve the variable in case you want to keep history data 
    %// (otherwise just initialize that to recv = [])
    recv = getappdata( hfig , 'LargeReceivedPacket' )

    %// now read all the input buffer until empty
    while hobj.BytesAvailable>0
        a=fscanf(hobj);
        recv=[recv a]
    end
    %// now do what you want with your received data
    %// this function will execute and return control to the main gui
    %// when terminated (when the input buffer is all read).
    %// it will be executed again each time the 'ByteAvailable' event is fired.
    %//
    %// if you did something with "recv" and want to save it, use setappdata again:
    setappdata( hfig , 'LargeReceivedPacket' , recv )        %// store it into APPDATA
```

Comment: This might work when you are dealing with a small amount of data. but in my case I'm making a simulation for Aloha protocol, therefore; I'm actually dealing with thousands of bytes. even the InputBufferSize and the OutputBufferSize cant take these data... So I have to palletize it first then start to transmit it.

Comment: @AbdulmalekNaes, you can adjust the input and output buffer size, and also adjust the number of byte (or the special character) to receive before the `BytesAvailable` event is triggered. Of course if the stream is long (or permanent) you'll have to process in more than one pass. I'm not sure I understand your concept of "palletize".

Comment: Thanks... I meant "packetize"; Dividing for example 9 million bytes into packets. each one has 50 thousands bytes...
Yes I know I can adjust the Buffer Size but the more you put the more errors appear and time out occur.

Comment: If your input is ~9Mb you can read it in chuncks, I updated the code to show you how to do it.

Comment: Hoki... I dont know how to thank you.. but I have question; 
What do you mean by "hfig" in  s.BytesAvailableFcn = {@myCustomReceiveFunction,hfig} ??

Comment: `hfig` is the handle of the main figure of your GUI. (for example, if you type `hfig=figure` in the console you open a new figure and you get the handle). Do you do your gui manually or with `GUIDE` ?

Comment: Then if you did it with guide, the figure handle should be in the `handles` variable. This variable contains the handles of the main graphic objects of your GUI. The figure handle should be the first field of this variable ... something like `handles.figure1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MATLAB, but in most programming environments you would have your infinite loop check for input on the serial port and then process any events from your GUI. If you change your inner `while` loop, you can do other things inside the `while(1)`:

```
recv=[];
while (1)
    while s.BytesAvailable>0
        a=fscanf(s);
        recv=[recv a]
    end

    ; Check for GUI events
end
```